# How to use mod_rewrite in a subdomain's .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a domain (let the name be) `mydomain.com`.
I added a subdomain, `sub.mydomain.com`. (It's an other site, the two sites don't have anything to do with each other)

I have mapped the subdomain (with godaddy.com's tool) to `/sub` directory. It works well with static file paths, ex. `http://sub.mydomain.com/js/script.js.php`.
However, I would like to be able to use the rewrite module to get `http://sub.mydomain.com/js/script.js`

My .htaccess files:

.htaccess in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mydomain.com/sub%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

.htaccess in the /sub directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^js/script\.js$ js/script.js.php [L]
```

(I tried adding `RewriteBase /sub/`, I didn't succeed).
It seems as if Apache didn't notice the `/sub`'s .htaccess

How can I get the rewrite work on the subdomain's paths?

Comment: Keep that `RewriteBase`: you need it because the rewrite is to a relative path.

Comment: The `.htaccess` is not literally in the `/sub` directory on your machine, is it? How are you mapping the URL `/sub` to a path name: is there an `Alias /sub /sub` (URL `/sub` goes to machine path `/sub`)?   What is the `DocumentRoot` of your `<VirtualHost>` handling these domains?

Comment: Suppose your `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/docroot`. Then the URL `/sub` will map to `/var/www/docroot/sub`, not to `/sub`. If you want `/sub` to go do `/sub`, this is a special exception to your docroot; you can install that with `Alias`.

Comment: thank you for the answer @Kaz.

The DocumentRoot is `/var/chroot/home/content/26/7464126/html`.
The mapping was made by the GUI tool of godaddy.com (the hosting service I use), I can't view `httpd.conf` and `rewrite.log` and I don't know whether `Alias` is set...

Under `/sub` directory I mean `'DocumentRoot'/sub`.

Comment: You really should get your own server, virtual or otherwise.

Comment: Was the root htaccess created by GoDaddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

After a long, exhausting debugging and googling I found an Apache setting that made the trouble:

I added `Options -MultiViews` and voilá, **it works**!

/////////////////////////////////////////////

**Now my configuration:**

-no .htaccess in the root.

-.htaccess in the root`/sub`:

```
DirectoryIndex site/index.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^site/js/script.js$ /site/js/script.js.php [L]
```